# Regex for currency value

Tags: c#, regex, currency-formatting

I have this regex that is working perfect to match currency values for U.S.A format ($1.50):

```
Regex money = new Regex(@"\w\^\$(\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*|(\d+))(\.\d{2})?$");
```

I'd like to have some help to UNDERSTAND how to build a regex like that, I need to change the format for my country, like change the *$* for *R$*.

I'm looking on msdn topics  but nothing worked so far...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has three parts, and to me it sounds like it is mostly about "learning how to fish", which is great.

**A. The Regex You Want **

Based on the comments, you are looking for this ([see demo](http://regex101.com/r/jP6fG8)):

```
^R\$\d+(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2}$
```

**B. Explanation of the Regex**

This is a relatively simple regex, and for this you can read an automatically-generated explanation. Several sites do this. Here is [one](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5Cw%5C%5E%5C$%28%5Cd%7B1,3%7D%28%5C,%5Cd%7B3%7D%29*%7C%28%5Cd%2b%29%29%28%5C.%5Cd%7B2%7D%29?$) (it will display better on the original site).

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------   \w                       word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------   \^                       '^'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------   \$                       '$'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------   (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{1,3}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 3 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2 (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \,                       ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d{3}                    digits (0-9) (3 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of \2 (NOTE: because you are using a
                             quantifier on this capture, only the
                             LAST repetition of the captured pattern
                             will be stored in \2)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------    |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------   )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------   (                        group and capture to \4 (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------   )?                       end of \4 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \4)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------   $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

**C. How Can I Learn to Build a Regex Like That**

Here are the resources I recommend.

1. Books: Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Ed), the Regex Cookbook
2. Websites: regular-expressions.info, RexEgg, [FAQ on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075)
3. Tools: RegexBuddy (commercial but outstanding debugger), regex101.com, Debuggex.com

Comment: If I drop the **R** *before* the **\$** and leave it like:  

*Regex money = new Regex(@"\w\^R\$(\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*|(\d+))(\.\d{2})?$");*. And I try to use the *isMatch* with the value *R$1,50* it still returning me false. WHy?

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro Several typos in what you sent. This is cleaner `^R\$(\d{1,3}(,\d{2})*|(\d+))?$` :) If you play with it in regex101.com you can see the results right away

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro Here's a [demo](http://regex101.com/r/nG6sX3) By the way the part after the `|` allows you to match more digits if there is no comma, is that what you want?

Comment: In USA you use currency format like *$1.50*. I need a regex to identify this format: *R$1,50*, *R$25,50*, *R$1.250,50*.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro Okay, thanks for explaining the exact format you need. I have made the regex for you and added it at the top of my answer. Please let me know if it works for you. :) [demo](http://regex101.com/r/jP6fG8)

Comment: Worked PERFECT !! Thank you for everything... I'll study a little deeper this Regex. Really thank your for answering me and explaining it!

Comment: You're very welcome, it was a pleasure. :) If you start studying regex and want to see something cool, bookmark [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174/match-or-replace-a-pattern-except-in-situations-s1-s2-s3-etc/23589204#23589204) for later, I'm really happy about this answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a `R` in your regex as so:

```
Regex rmoney = new Regex(@"\w\^R\$(\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*|(\d+))(\.\d{2})?$");
```

Comment: Is there a tutorial/article or something that could make me understand how to build one ? I jsut don't understand these slashes brackets etc... ;s